# Laravel API with large datasets very slow in loading

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, api

I have developed a `Laravel` application with api routes that load the data from mysql db, the controller action executes a nested DB query and returns a collection; by default Laravel converts returned collection to JSON, below is my contrller action:

```
public function index()
    {
        $admin0 = 2;

        return DB::table('commodities_monthly_prices as CMP')
            ->join('locations', 'CMP.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
            ->where('locations.admin0', $admin0)
            ->join('global_admins', 'locations.admin0', '=', 'global_admins.admin0_code')
            ->join('commodities', 'CMP.commodity_id', '=', 'commodities.id')
            ->join('price_types', 'CMP.price_type_id', '=', 'price_types.id')
            ->join('measure_units', 'CMP.measure_unit_id', '=', 'measure_units.id')
            ->select('commodities.name AS commodity_name', 'price_types.name AS type_name',
                'measure_units.name AS unit_name', 'global_admins.admin0_code AS admin0',
                'global_admins.admin0_name AS country_name', 'global_admins.admin1_code AS admin1',
                'global_admins.admin1_name AS governorate_name')
            ->selectRaw('date(concat_WS(\'-\', CMP.price_year, CMP.price_month, \'01\')) as date, ROUND(AVG(CMP.price) / 1000, 3) as price')
            ->groupBy('date', 'commodity_name', 'type_name', 'unit_name', 'global_admins.admin0_name',
                'global_admins.admin0_code', 'global_admins.admin1_name', 'global_admins.admin1_code')
            ->orderBy('date')
            ->orderBy('commodity_name')
            ->get();
    }
```

Number of returned JSON objects more than 50000 objects and take about 90 seconds to finish loading, the only thing came to my mind is to change the response from JSON to CSV (will this help) as the front-end library accepts JSON and CSV http response, if this helps please tell me how to do it? if I need a third party library?

Please advie me how I can make the action loads faster.

Thank you for your help,

```
SELECT `commodities`.`name` AS `commodity_name`,
       `price_types`.`name` AS `type_name`,
       `measure_units`.`name` AS `unit_name`,
       `global_admins`.`admin0_code` AS `admin0`,
       `global_admins`.`admin0_name` AS `country_name`,
       `global_admins`.`admin1_code` AS `admin1`,
       `global_admins`.`admin1_name` AS `governorate_name`,
       ROUND(AVG(CMP.price) / 1000, 3) AS price
FROM `commodities_monthly_prices` AS `CMP`
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `CMP`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
INNER JOIN `global_admins` ON `locations`.`admin0` = `global_admins`.`admin0_code`
INNER JOIN `commodities` ON `CMP`.`commodity_id` = `commodities`.`id`
INNER JOIN `price_types` ON `CMP`.`price_type_id` = `price_types`.`id`
INNER JOIN `measure_units` ON `CMP`.`measure_unit_id` = `measure_units`.`id`
WHERE `locations`.`admin0` = ?
GROUP BY `CMP`.`price_year`,
         `CMP`.`price_month`,
         `commodity_name`,
         `type_name`,
         `unit_name`,
         `global_admins`.`admin0_name`,
         `global_admins`.`admin0_code`,
         `global_admins`.`admin1_name`,
         `global_admins`.`admin1_code`
ORDER BY `commodity_name` ASC
```

Comment: Optimize/index your database? Use pagination to return 500 instead of 50000?

Comment: get the raw query. Include `EXPLAIN {query}` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the tables involved.

Comment: Rather than `group by date`, use `groupBy CMP.price_year, CMP.price_month`

Comment: I can't use pagination as in the frond end I am using `PivotTable.js` https://pivottable.js.org/examples/ which needs all of the records to do analysis;

Comment: @danblack this is a `gist` contains the tables and raw query: https://gist.github.com/yabasha/d36acf539f32af70b72f394b8e45404a

thank you for your help,

Comment: You can use pagination and caching or even GraphQL for even better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you need `INDEX(admin0)` on `Locations`.

You don't need a datatype that goes into the billions for this:  `price_month` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL.  `INT` takes 4 bytes; `TINYINT` takes only 1.  And many of the other columns are bigger than necessary.  This has an impact on disk space and query speed.

If this is a "year", I hope you are not comparing it to an INT:  `str_year0` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

`commodities_monthly_prices` has both prices and a description of the commodities (market, currency, etc).  The description is probably constant, so probably should be in a separate table.

Your Question is about the speed of loading.  Is it coming from a CSV file via `LOAD DATA`?  If so, I suggest you load it into a table that is tailored to what the incoming data looks like.  Then massage the data -- normalization, cleanse, fix typos, etc.  Finally copy the data into the tables you want for analysis.  *These tables are not necessarily in the same form as the raw data.*  This would, for example give you a chance to split `commodities_monthly_prices`.

A no-no in schema design is to have multiple columns representing an array.  I am thinking of str_year, admin_name, etc.  Since I don't understand their purpose, I don't have a specific recommendation other than to say that the restructuring I described above is the time to fix that.

You mentioned JSON, but I don't see such in the Schema.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, the JSON i am talking about is the return from laravel controller to the view, when laravel reads the query it reads the query into array of collection and laravel by default any array or collection it converts the response to array of json objects

Comment: @YaBasha - I would _expect_ the conversion to JSON to be not relevant.  You can verify that by removing the conversion to  JSON.

Comment: I thought the reason would be the conversion because when checking response, size in chrome network panel, is 12mb

Comment: @YaBasha - Your JSON string is that big?

Comment: It is a dataset for different commodities prices in countries and the Front-end library needs the whole set to do analysis

Comment: @YaBasha - See if you can instrument the code enough to determine which step of the process is slowest.  SELECT / network / parsing JSON / etc.

Comment: Thanx for your help